# Run another app, if fails open Google Play

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play

I'm just trying to run my app from another one. Don't have any problems with that, I'm using this code for that:

```
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"); 
    ComponentName n = new 
    ComponentName("de.yanniks.myapp", 
    "de.yanniks.myapp.MyAppActivity"); 
    i.setComponent(n); 
    startActivity(i);
```

The problem is that the app crashes if the called app is not installed. Instead of that, I would like to open the Google Play site of the app, so the user can download it. How to I do that?

Please Help!

Comment: Does your app also crash when you encapsulate the code above in a try catch Throwable block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
try {
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"); 
    ComponentName n = new 
    ComponentName("de.yanniks.myapp", 
    "de.yanniks.myapp.MyAppActivity"); 
    i.setComponent(n); 
    startActivity(i); 
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=de.yanniks.myapp"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I've typed this code out straight into the answer box, so there may be an error here or there, but that's the general gist of it.